# Associative arrays in javascript is a bug?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

We know JavaScript does not support arrays with named indexes. (Associative arrays)
But when we declare an associative array in javascript, it doesn't throw an error And it works surprisingly.

```js
let arr = [];
arr.name = 'John';
arr.lastName = 'Doe';
arr.age = 46;

let obj = {name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 46};
```

When `console.log('arr')`, it will show:

```js
[name: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: 46] //Shown with a special array sign
   age: 46
   lastName: "Doe"
   name: "John"
   length: 0
   __proto__: Array(0) //Shown Array Not Object
```

AND:

```js
console.log(arr instanceof Array);  //true
console.log(arr instanceof Object); //true

console.log(obj instanceof Array);  //false
console.log(obj instanceof Object); //true
```

As you see, Javascript displays an associative array with an array specific sign. `[]` (bracket)
But it treats as an object with that array Because some array methods and properties (like `length`) will produce incorrect results.
Also, if JavaScript works with this type of array as an object, why does not use the special mark for the object? `{}` (curly bracket)
In short, is this a bug in the JavaScript interpreter or a type of ability?

Comment: Javascript does not have associative arrays, and setting properties of an array object is not "using" the array part.

Comment: Not a bug.... you are using an array to create an *"array like object"*. `typeof []` will return `'object'` also as there is no `'array'` type

Comment: from the standard: "*An Array object is an exotic object that gives special treatment to array index property keys ...*"

Comment: @charlietfl `typeof [1,2,3]` is also `object`, becuse In JavaScript array is an object. also did you get the `console.log`? it's show with an array specific sign.

Comment: @MR.Mostafa of course it will. Completely irrelevant if it is a populated or empty array. How the console handles output is also irrelevant and will vary depending on environment

Comment: @James But why is show with an array specific sign Not object sign?

Comment: You are just adding properties to the Object (see prototype of Array) - this is what would be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, an array is not only "treated as" an object -- it IS an object. As you have already seen, since `arr instanceof Object` is true.

Therefore, as with all objects, you can assign properties to an array.

`length` is a special property of arrays, and represents the number of array elements. Since, in your example, `arr` has no elements, its `length` property is correctly 0. Objects do not automatically have a special `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

The Array is an object - it brings its own methods you can use.
The object is not an array - you cant use the methods of the Array-object.

I found this text what describes it with a few words: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/arrayobject.htm